# Search Vimeo comments only

Tags: api, search, comments, vimeo

I need to be able to search vimeo comments. I do see an API for searching videos but I want to search only comments. Any API to do that? Or, if there is an API to get the latest comments in Vimeo that would help since I can index comments in Elasticsearch.

I searched the documentation of vimeo and found the video search API but not comments.

My final result should contain a list of latest/fresh comments from Vimeo.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#working-with-headers), the endpoint is

```
/videos/{video_id}/comments
```

Comment: thanks! this is not a search API. I have to have the video id to get all comments on it.

Comment: No, I don't think you can search through every comment on every video on Vimeo.